# Does rename a file cost money on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have defined my object-name and want to optimize them for performance reason.

so it is a move within the bucket

```
aws s3 mv
```

Does that cost money ? I have millions of objects. What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it costs money (source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=455101#jive-message-455306).

If you have 5 millions files to rename and follow the same steps than the aws support gave, the costs should be under 60$.

## Edit (2023)

Following the deletion of the aws forum post, here is an updated answer.

AWS S3 doesn't support moving a file natively. It does support the COPY and DELETE operation which is most likely what the CLI is using.

If you have 5 millions files on S3 US East, 1,000 COPY operations costs $0.005 and DELETE requests are free. If you need to list all the files in your bucket, the LIST operation costs the same and returns 1,000 items maximum per call.

This brings the total COPY cost to $5, and the LIST cost to $0.5. It should cost $5.5.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/.

Comment: uri link broken

Comment: I've updated the answer following aws deleting the forum post.